# locking custom module function

Tags: 7

In my custom module, I would like to acquire lock on a particular function which will allow only one process to execute that piece of code at a time and then allow other process and so on. So that the code does not run in parallel.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do I understand your question right, when I assume that you like to block it for all parallel requests running on the same server?

Comment: yes, suppose if two users clicks on 'confirm button' at the same time, then the code/function should run one at a time based on which process/request locks the function first and other process wait for the lock release. Ultimately maintaining a queue.

Comment: Drupal has an API right for locking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal provides its own [locking mechanisms](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!lock.inc/group/lock/7).

> In most environments, multiple Drupal page requests (a.k.a. threads or processes) will execute in parallel. This leads to potential conflicts or race conditions when two requests execute the same code at the same time. A common example of this is a rebuild like [`menu_rebuild()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) where we invoke many hook implementations to get and process data from all active modules, and then delete the current data in the database to insert the new afterwards.
>
> This is a cooperative, advisory lock system. Any long-running operation that could potentially be attempted in parallel by multiple requests should try to acquire a lock before proceeding. By obtaining a lock, one request notifies any other requests that a specific operation is in progress which must not be executed in parallel.
>
> To use this API, pick a unique name for the lock. A sensible choice is the name of the function performing the operation. A very simple example use of this API:
>
> ```
> function mymodule_long_operation() {
>   if (lock_acquire('mymodule_long_operation')) {
>     // Do the long operation here.
>     // ...
>     lock_release('mymodule_long_operation');
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If a function acquires a lock it should always release it when the operation is complete by calling [`lock_release()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21lock.inc/function/lock_release/7), as in the example.

A function that has acquired a lock may attempt to renew a lock (extend the duration of the lock) by calling [`lock_acquire()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21lock.inc/function/lock_acquire/7) again during the operation. Failure to renew a lock is indicative that another request has acquired the lock, and that the current operation may need to be aborted.
>
If a function fails to acquire a lock it may either immediately return, or it may call `lock_wait()` if the rest of the current page request requires that the operation in question be complete. After [`lock_wait()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21lock.inc/function/lock_wait/7) returns, the function may again attempt to acquire the lock, or may simply allow the page request to proceed on the assumption that a parallel request completed the operation.

In Drupal 8, the example code would not be much different.

```
function mymodule_long_operation() {
  $lock = \Drupal::lock();
  if ($lock->acquire('mymodule_long_operation')) {
    // Do the long operation here.
    // ...
    $lock->release('mymodule_long_operation');
  }
}
```

See  [`\Drupal\Core\Lock\LockBackendInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Lock!LockBackendInterface.php/interface/LockBackendInterface/8) for the interface exposed by the locking service.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my above comment, you could use a lock file on your system / a database stored setting value of your module. Once the process is in use, it should write that flag. After the process finished, the flag should be removed.

If the process is triggered by another request, it has to check for the presence of this flag first and wait until it vanishes.

This would solve your problem of not running in parallel. BUT this will also block the second request, leading to longer wait times for the end-user. And end-users can be quite unpatient. Speaking of pushing the button multiple times, or reloading the page, because they don't see any progress.

Therefore you should additionally consider implementing a kind of enqueuing the tasks, that does not require the entire request to wait.