# How to make a lock forget?

Tags: 8

I understand how locks work, thanks to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188904/locking-custom-module-function).  Very straightforward:

```
function mymodule_long_operation() {
  if (lock_acquire('mymodule_long_operation')) {
    // Do the long operation here.
    // ...
    lock_release('mymodule_long_operation');
  }
}
```

My problem is that my function can get "stuck" if lock_release is never hit. So how can I get my function to work again if something goes wrong here:

```
function mymodule_long_operation() {
  if (lock_acquire('mymodule_long_operation')) {
    // SOMETHING GOES WRONG HERE!
    lock_release('mymodule_long_operation');
  }
}
```

Yes, I can put the whole function around a try/catch and release the lock in the catch. But as a developer, I often add "die()" in my code when working. So I can easily trigger this function into an unexecutable state.

Is there some way to make the lock expire after a while? Or to make the lock expire as part of some gauranteed garbage collection function?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

** UPDATE **

Nevermind me adding die() in my code. What if the function times out? Then it wont reach the release. I'm sure there are more cases to validate this as a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to make the lock expire after a while?

`lock_acquire` takes a second parameter, defining the lifetime of the lock:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21lock.inc/function/lock_acquire/7.x

The Drupal 8 version would be:

`lock->acquire($name, $timeout);`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Lock%21DatabaseLockBackend.php/function/DatabaseLockBackend%3A%3Aacquire/8.2.x

Comment: Rad! But any idea where that parameter lives in Drupal 8?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. it's lock->acquire($name, $timeout)!

Comment: Sorry. Thought this question was for Drupal 7.

Comment: @Kevin You can update the answer for the Drupal 8 part.